# checking new time valid within a fixed time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a function in javascript to check if the time is valid or not, i.e if the new time (has start and end time) is in between a fixed time (has start and end time), it is valid, otherwise invalid.

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Luufjwq/)**

My code is as given below

Here it is giving valid when i give invalid times

```
var fixedTime = {start : '2014-11-13T09:00:00', end : '2014-11-13T13:00:00'};
var newTime = {start : '2014-11-13T06:30:00', end : '2014-11-13T08:30:00'};

if(checkDates(fixedTime, newTime))
{
    window.alert("Valid");
}
else
{
   window.alert("Invalid");
}
function checkDates(fixedTime, newTime)
{
    var returnBoolean = true;
       if(((new Date(newTime.start).getTime()) <= (new Date(fixedTime.start).getTime()) && (new Date(newTime.start).getTime()) >= (new Date(fixedTime.end).getTime())) || ((new Date(newTime.end).getTime()) <= (new Date(fixedTime.start).getTime()) && (new Date(newTime.end).getTime()) >= (new Date(fixedTime.end).getTime())))
       {
           returnBoolean = false;
       }

    return returnBoolean;
}
```

can anyone please tell me some solutions for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for such enormous complexity.  You only need to make two comparisons:

```
var fixedTime = {
    start: new Date('2014-11-13T09:00:00').getTime(),
    end: new Date('2014-11-13T13:00:00').getTime()
};
var newTime = {
    start: new Date('2014-11-13T06:30:00').getTime(),
    end: new Date('2014-11-13T08:30:00').getTime()
};

if (checkDates(fixedTime, newTime)) {
    alert("Valid");
} else {
    alert("Invalid");
}

function checkDates(fixedTime, newTime) {
    return newTime.start > fixedTime.start && newTime.end < fixedTime.end;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Luufjwq/1/)